# read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)

Tags: node.js, next.js

I Suddenly got the below issue when I tried to run my next js project. it was run perfectly before and this happen without any changes in the system. Any idea regarding this

````
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc.js" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
info  - Using external babel configuration from /Users/subodha/Subodha/lab/rpm-web/.babelrc.js
postcss-resolve-url: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:211:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v17.2.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
subodha@Subodhas-MacBook-Pro rpm-web %```
````

Answer (score 0):

I gave the same error.
To solve them, I disabled my VPN connection and built it successfully.
so this error should happen for your network connection.

Answer (score -1):

i got the same error when i was using a vpn or without a vpn.

using another vpn solved this issue.